# Mapping locations satisfying condition in array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, mapping, conditional-statements

Given a logical array (True/False values) and a range of indices that may not start at 0, I want to create a new array of same size as that range, where each element contains the index of the nearest preceding True.

Example with a logical array such as:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

and a subset of indices:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`  (here, starts at 0 but may not have to)

result would be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]
```

I have a working solution (below) but i'm looking for alternatives, either faster and/or more elegant and/or more readable, given that the size of the arrays can vary from thousands to millions.

```
import numpy as np

def map_nearest_preceding_true_indices(tmask, irange):

    true_indices = np.where(tmask)[0]
    mapped_indices = np.empty(len(irange), dtype=np.int)

    for i, index in enumerate(irange):
        index_loc = np.where(true_indices <= index)[0][-1]
        mapped_indices[i] = true_indices[index_loc]

    return mapped_indices
```

Comment: What if the entire array has 0's?

Comment: @SruthiV The overarching scenario enforced this cannot happen whenever that function would  be involved.

Comment: Any feedback on the updated solutions?

Comment: @Divakar Tested just now. It works great! Thank you. I timed both solutions with larger arrays, tmask of size 5000 with True/False dispatched at random and idx_range of size 1000. Your solution takes ~0.3 ms and the one from "agubelu" takes ~ 1.2 ms. I'm surprised that the latter using generator is slower.

Comment: @Wall-E I am sensing some under-appreciation for NumPy there :) NumPy is meant for performance and as such, I am not surprised.

Comment: @Divakar I agree. Here the processing time discrepancies seem to increase proportionally with matrix sizes in favor of the Numpy solution, although I found some academic elegance in the non-numpy solution and I learned something new with it. I might end up doing that kind of process repeatedly on very big matrices so i'll stick to Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def map_locations(tmask, irange, invalid_index=-1):
    idx = np.where(tmask)[0]
    sidx = np.searchsorted(idx, irange, 'right')-1
    return np.where(sidx==-1,invalid_index, idx[sidx])
```

Sample runs -

```
In [124]: # Considering a more generic case
     ...: tmask = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool)
     ...: irange = np.array([4, 8, 11, 18])

In [125]: map_locations(tmask, irange, invalid_index=-1)
Out[125]: array([4, 7, 9, 9])

In [129]: # Original case with first mask element being false
     ...: tmask = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool).tolist()
     ...: irange = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 17]).tolist()

In [130]: map_locations(tmask, irange, invalid_index=-1)
Out[130]: array([-1, -1, -1,  3,  4,  5,  5,  9])
```

Comment: As I was saying to @agublu, possible issue when the 1st element is False. Data are meant to start with True though. Your method seems to cycle around the data by giving ```array([9, 9, 9, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7])``` where the method from @agublu fails, which I'd rather have so I'm aware my data are wrong (that mistake being possible for now).

Comment: @Wall-E Added a param `invalid_index` to handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have a one-liner list comprehension:

```
data = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

nearest_true = [next(v for v in range(ind, -1, -1) if data[v]) for ind in indices]
```

For each index in the indices array, `next` traverses the data array backwards starting at that index and returns the first index for the data array that contains a truthy value.

However, as discussed in the comments, this code would fail if any index does not have at least one truthy value at or behind it. We can solve this by  providing a default value for `next()` passing it as a second parameter, in this case we'd have to parenthesize the generator as it's no longer the only argument:

```
NOT_FOUND = -1
nearest_true = [next((v for v in range(ind, -1, -1) if data[v]), NOT_FOUND) 
                for ind in indices]
```

Then, the output for `data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` would be `[-1, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]`

Comment: @SruthiV The inner `for` starts from the index and goes backwards until it finds the first True value in the data array, so I don't think it'll have a big performance toll.

Comment: I add never used generators before. In what aspect is it better than e.g: ```nearest_true = [[v for v in range(ind, -1, -1) if data[v]][0] for ind in indices]```? Is it because not all values would actually be calculated, leading to efficiency gains?

Comment: @Wall-E using that approach, the whole inner list would be generated before picking the first element using `[0]`, which isn't very efficient since we only need the first element. However, the generator itself doesn't compute any elements until `next()` is called on it, resulting in the first element that matches the condition.

Comment: From the given example, changing it a bit, this method fails if first data element is False: ```data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]```. @Divakar method does not but cycles around the data, output being ```array([9, 9, 9, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7])```. Data are meant to start with True anyway though so it's not really a problem but i'd rather have it crash rather than giving an answer scientifically incorrect.

Comment: Well, actually, it would fail if any desired index does not have at least one True value at or behind it. I'll edit my answer to take this into account.

Comment: I find it a very elegant solution. I will probably stick to the Numpy one as I need to consider also performance. Thanks for showing this alternative, it makes me more aware of what generators are and do.